# How can we add IntelliSense to visual studio in time of nhibernate mapping file editing?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, nhibernate, xsd, intellisense

How can we add IntelliSense to visual studio in time of nhibernate mapping file editing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add NHibernate XML schema to Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565156/how-to-add-nhibernate-xml-schema-to-visual-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see http://jameskovacs.com/2007/10/16/enabling-intellisense-for-nhibernate/

Comment: That's NOT the recommended way to do it.

Comment: That link is broken, try this (for VS2010) instead:  http://www.jameswampler.com/index.php/2010/06/03/adding-the-nhibernate-schema-files-to-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 5):

Include the **xsd** files that come with NHibernate as part of your solution (either within a project, or as "Solution Files").

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Visual Studio which XML schema to use for these mapping files. Maybe this is what you need:

http://blog.benday.com/archive/2006/01/15/3646.aspx