# How to add NHibernate XML schema to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nhibernate, intellisense

I'm learning NHibernate and I added `<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">` to `App.config`. Visual Studio reported a message:

> Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2:hibernate-configuration'.

I know this is not a problem, but if VS knew the schema, IntelliSense would work. How can I add the schema?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Copy the two `.xsd` from the folder `Required_Bins` from the NHibernate download to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas. If you use other version of VS than 2008 (or if you have VS installed elsewhere), change the path accordingly.

Comment: This is NOT the recommended way.

Comment: @Kugel, I do realize that. But I still think it's better this way.

Answer (score 23):

Just include the XSD files in any of your projects or as Solution Items.

Comment: So I have to do this for every solution that uses NHibernate? That seems like a useless work, when I can do it once and forget about it.

Comment: You have to add a reference to NHibernate to every solution that uses it. How is this step any different?

Comment: It's different, because it can be easily avoided.

Comment: Also, NHibernate documentation recommends copying the to the Visual Studio directory.

Comment: And it's wrong (I'll upload a patch for that). It might have been correct for VS2003, but it's not the recommended method anymore.

Answer (score 13):

For those using nuget, and multiple versions of nHibernate, Source control, et al...

1. Open up the hbm XML file in your project.
2. Select the XML menu item and select `Schemas` in the drop down (or press <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>)
3. Click `Add`
4. Browse to your Solution and open the `packages` folder in the root
5. Find the nHibernate package folder
6. Select both the XSD files within the `lib` folder

Answer (score 7):

I tried some of the above ideas with VS2012 and NHibernate  3.3.1.4000 and it did not work, but the following [tip](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arnona/archive/2011/01/11/tip-of-the-day-on-nhibernate-intellisense-for-the-hbm-files.aspx) given by [ArnonA](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arnona/) worked for me. It should also be SVN safe, if you work on multiple projects with different versions of nHibernate

1. Inside VS2012, open up the nHibernate xml file you would like to edit.
2. Once in the xml file editor, the XML menu should be visible in the main VS menu.
3. Click on XML->Schemas menu, this should open the "XML Schemas" dialog.
4. Add the "nhibernate-configuration.xsd" and "nhibernate-mapping.xsd" files and click ok.
5. Done :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, link-only answers are not very welcomed -- think about that link becoming unavailable or the page/site going offline; in which case, your answer loses its usefulness. Please quote/include in your answer the highlighted and important points that help answer the original question. Take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more info.

Comment: @Jesse: Thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction, appreciate it :).

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the `nhibernate.xxx.xsd` files into your

```
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio %version%\xml\Schemas
```

folder.

Comment: This is NOT the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

You should add xsd files to the solution. This would prevent issues of missing files if your team needs to download the project from a code repository.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Would it be possible to explain why to use your solution and show some examples of those file?  I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.